# How to parse an AIML file locally on an IOS application?

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, swift, aiml

I currently have a basic AIML parser written in python. I am trying to integrate that into my IOS application. I cannot find a method to call a Python file in my swift application. Below is the AIML Parser code:

```
import aiml
import sys
import os

session_id = xxxx


def getChatbotResults(botInput):
    myChatbot = aiml.Kernel()
    myChatbot.learn('new.aiml')
    final_result = myChatbot.respond(botInput, session_id)
    return final_result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    query = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
    getChatbotResults(query)
```

Is there a way to parse AIML files locally in SWIFT or Objective-C?
Or is there a way to run this python file inside my IOS project, with the relevant imports

Comment: AIML appears to be XML. It's easy enough to parse XML in Swift or Objective-C. Do you just want parse the XML to extract value from it or do you want to actually do AI processing with the file? Those are two completely different tasks.

Comment: I have an chatbot, which is written in AIML, the current python parser uses AIML, and does actual processing with the file. I would like to do the same natively

Comment: iOS does not provide any built-in support for AIML. You will have to do some searching for 3rd party libraries you might be able use.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find anything. So I thought that maybe I can use my python file which has support for AIML. However I don't know if I can run this python file in my IOS app

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off parsing the code some other way, but it is possible to run Python from within an iOS app. PyObjC is one way to do it. There is a tutorial introduction to it [here](https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/tutorials/embedded.html).

Comment: Hi, is this for embedding python into IOS app or for MacOS, because I was reading and found that apple allowed embedding python into MacOS/OSX. But they didn't state anything for IOS.

Comment: Apple used to be pretty picky about interpreters on iOS devices, even blocking them for a time. This is no longer true. One of my own programs is techBASIC(http://www.byteworks.us/Byte_Works/techBASIC.html), which is a compiled/interpreted language along the lines of the old UCSD P-system, or Java without a JIT compiler. In addition to allowing techBASIC, Apple also has allowed several apps written in techBASIC on the app store. In short, I don't think there will be any problem getting an app through the app review process using Python. Frankly, I doubt if they would even notice.